# htaccess redirect stuck in infinite recursion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I seem to have a strange problem that's only happening on one machine and not the other, the apache2 version on this one is 2.4.23 (the not working one), and on the working one I have apache version 2.4.10.

The rewrite snippet I have redirects URLs without extensions to .html internally if the file exists and looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

I remove this piece the redirect loops stops, but obviously my extensionless URLs no longer get redirected.

I've evolved it to this, which I thought for sure to stop the redirect problem, but still loops forever

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?(?!\.html/)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Enabling the debug log level on the apache server in question gives a ton of lines that look similar to this one

```
[Wed May 30 11:49:25.669176 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4292] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:63613] xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [domain.com/sid#7f30066c1328][rid#7f2fff7d5718/initial/redir#9] [perdir /domains/domain.com/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '2012/06/some-blog-post/privacy.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html'
[Wed May 30 11:49:25.669200 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4292] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:63613] xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [domain.com/sid#7f30066c1328][rid#7f2fff7d5718/initial/redir#9] [perdir /domains/domain.com/public_html/] add path info postfix: /domains/domain.com/public_html/2012/06/some-blog-post -> /domains/domain.com/public_html/2012/06/some-blog-post/privacy.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
[Wed May 30 11:49:25.669215 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4292] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:63613] xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [domain.com/sid#7f30066c1328][rid#7f2fff7d5718/initial/redir#9] [perdir /domains/domain.com/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /domains/domain.com/public_html/2012/06/some-blog-post/privacy.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html -> 2012/06/some-blog-post/privacy.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
```

I'm afraid I'm not super well versed with the htaccess syntax so maybe I'm missing something obvious

---

Here's the entire htaccess file (sorry it's a tad lengthy)

```
RedirectMatch   301 ^/quote/?$              /pricing
RedirectMatch   301 ^/order\.htm/?$         /order
RedirectMatch   301 ^/contact\.htm/?$       /contact
RedirectMatch   301 ^/coin-gallery\.htm/?$  /gallery
RedirectMatch   301 ^/gallery-html/?$       /gallery

RedirectMatch   301 ^/baseball-html/?$      /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/softball-html/?$      /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/volleyball-html/?$    /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/basketball-html/?$    /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/football-html/?$      /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/soccer-html/?$        /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/hockey-html/?$        /baseball-trading-pins


##blogs-500s
RedirectMatch   301 ^/tag.*$        /blog
RedirectMatch   301 ^/wp.*$         /blog
RedirectMatch   301 ^/category\/.*$         /blog
RedirectMatch   301 ^/[^a-zA-Z]+$   /blog


##pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/sitemap-html/?$                   /
RedirectMatch   301 ^/quote_lapelpins\.html/?$          /
RedirectMatch   301 ^/custom-html/?$                    /custom-lapel-pin-styles    
RedirectMatch   301 ^/softenamel-html/?$                /soft-enamel-pins   
RedirectMatch   301 ^/cardstock-html/?$                 /cardstock  
RedirectMatch   301 ^/employee-html/?$                  /employee-recognition-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/employee-recognition/?$           /employee-recognition-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/baseball-html/?$                  /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/softball-html/?$                  /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/volleyball-html/?$                /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/basketball-html/?$                /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/football-html/?$                  /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/usssaquote_tradingpins\.html/?$   /custom-usssa-trading-pins?lid=Ij2
RedirectMatch   307 ^/soccer-html/?$                    /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/hockey-html/?$                    /baseball-trading-pins  
RedirectMatch   307 ^/cloisonne-html/?$                 /cloisonne-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/pin-pricing/?$                    /pricing
RedirectMatch   301 ^/rush-pins-2/?$                    /rush-pins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/baseball\.html/?$                 /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/softball\.html/?$                 /baseball-trading-pins  
RedirectMatch   307 ^/soccer\.html/?$                   /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/volleyball\.html/?$               /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/basketball\.html/?$               /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/football\.html/?$                 /baseball-trading-pins
RedirectMatch   307 ^/hockey\.html/?$                   /baseball-trading-pins  
RedirectMatch   301 ^/contactus-html/?$                 /contact
RedirectMatch   301 ^/aboutus-html/?$                   /about-us
RedirectMatch   301 ^/aboutus\.html/?$                  /about-us
RedirectMatch   301 ^/aboutus\.htm/?$                   /about-us
RedirectMatch   301 ^/termsandconditions-html/?$        /terms
RedirectMatch   301 ^/termsandconditions\.html/?$       /terms
RedirectMatch   301 ^/privacy-htm/?$                    /privacy
RedirectMatch   301 ^/presentation\.html/?$             /presentation-options
RedirectMatch   301 ^/presentation-html/?$              /presentation-options
RedirectMatch   301 ^/attachments\.html/?$              /attachments
RedirectMatch   301 ^/attachments-html/?$               /attachments
RedirectMatch   301 ^/platingchart\.html/?$             /plating
RedirectMatch   301 ^/platingchart-html/?$              /plating
RedirectMatch   301 ^/gemstones\.html/?$                /gemstones
RedirectMatch   301 ^/trading-pin-options/?$            /baseball-trading-pins  
RedirectMatch   301 ^/trading-pin-gallery/?$            /gallery
RedirectMatch   301 ^/trading-pin-gallery-2/?$          /gallery    
RedirectMatch   301 ^/trading-pin-gallery-3/?$          /gallery
RedirectMatch   301 ^/trading-pin-gallery-4/?$          /gallery
RedirectMatch   301 ^/artwork\.html/?$                  /artwork
RedirectMatch   301 ^/artwork-html/?$                   /artwork
RedirectMatch   301 ^/keychains-html/?$                 /keychains
RedirectMatch   301 ^/challengecoins-html/?$            /custom-challenge-coins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/medallions-html/?$                /medals-medallions  
RedirectMatch   301 ^/wristbands-html/?$                /custom-wristbands
RedirectMatch   301 ^/lanyards-html/?$                  /lanyards
RedirectMatch   301 ^/quote_tradingpins\.html/?$        /custom-usssa-trading-pins?lid=Ij2
RedirectMatch   301 ^/usssa-pins/?$                     /custom-usssa-trading-pins?lid=Ij2
RedirectMatch   301 ^/contactus\.html/?$                /contact
RedirectMatch   301 ^/fraternitysorority-html/?$        /fraternity-and-sorority-pins


##coins
RedirectMatch   301 ^/coin-bottle-openers\.htm/?$   /coin-bottle-openers
RedirectMatch   301 ^/coin-gallery\.htm/?$          /gallery
RedirectMatch   301 ^/coin-gallery.*$               /gallery
RedirectMatch   301 ^/coin-pricing\.htm/?$          /pricing
RedirectMatch   301 ^/create\.htm/?$                /create
RedirectMatch   301 ^/presentation.htm/?$           /coin-presentation-options
RedirectMatch   301 ^/history\.htm/?$               /challenge-coin-history
RedirectMatch   301 ^/faq\.htm/?$                   /faq
RedirectMatch   301 ^/testimonials\.htm/?$          /testimonials
RedirectMatch   301 ^/quote/?$                      /create
RedirectMatch   301 ^/quote/view(\.php)?$           /view

##patches
RedirectMatch   301 ^/pvc-patches/?$    /pvc







<Files "header.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "footer.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "config.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "version">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "superheader.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404   /404.html
ErrorDocument 500   /505.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?(?!\.html/)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?img/([A-Fa-f0-9]{64}).gif$ /scripts/trackemail.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Whoops! I forgot the URL, that should have been first thing I listed, but the path in this example would be

> /2012/06/some-blog-post/privacy

---

This is the apache2 response headers when that URL is loaded

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 06 Jun 2018 14:54:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 666
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

I grabbed a bit more (a ton) of the apache2 log after enabling the debug LogLevel and put it here https://pastebin.com/pu5sUJnG, adding `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` to my apache2.conf file

Comment: @anubhava sure thing, but do note that removing the code in question stops the redirect loop

Comment: @anubhava oh duh, that should have have been the first thing I listed "/2012/06/some-blog-post/privacy"

Comment: @anubhava it also should be noted that a file doesn't (not even an html file) exist at that path, but there is a "/privacy.html" file at the root is that could be causing some weird issues

Comment: @anubhava I thought about the browser caching but I'm getting the errors in the apache2 log, so that shouldn't be the case

Comment: @anubhava yup same problem, tried in incog Chrome and private Firefox, sorry for the delayed responses I had a surgery that took me away for some time

Comment: @anubhava thanks! And I've appended them to the question

Comment: @anubhava The URL is exactly the same as it is in the address bar, it just throws the 500 immediately and stops

Comment: @anubhava yeah the redirect loop I think is purely internal, according to what the log says anyway with the message `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have **just this code** in your site root .htaccess and retest with `RewriteLog` enabled:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes +MultiViews

# commenting out for now
#ErrorDocument 404   /404.html
#ErrorDocument 500   /505.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^img/([a-f0-9]{64})\.gif$ scripts/trackemail.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Enabling `MultiViews` will make Apace serve correct matching `.php` or `.html` files. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html

Comment: Same thing is before, without Log debug enabled I get just `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: And I'm grabbing th elog level debug now

Comment: Yup, it was only that, copied and pasted, nothing else

Comment: It's a tad lengthy, but I've pasted a ton of it's output https://pastebin.com/pu5sUJnG

Comment: Oh you're right, hmm that's strange I'll try to push it again

Comment: Yeah I pushed it to the wrong site :) got it this time https://pastebin.com/0WJkL9qe

Comment: The response in this case seemed to be just a simple 404 error

Comment: Should just be a 404 error like it is with that htaccess file, the plan is that so if the file does exist (but with an html extension) then it the html file is served. Essentially this is just to hide the file extensions, but this particular case is causing issues that I seem unable to resolve

Comment: The real link here was supposed to be `domain.com/privacy` which loads the `priavcy.html` file at the root, but there was a broken link in our footer that had the href set to only `privacy`, so when in the blog post at `/month/year/post-title` the link would take the user to `/month/year/post-title/privacy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172612/discussion-between-anubhava-and-brian-leishman).

Comment: I've added a bounty for this question for your answer since you were beyond helpful, I'll award it when SO lets me :)

Comment: I fell onto what seems to be a another solution, just in case your curious I've added a second answer, you'rs is till the one I'm selecting though

Answer (score 1):

Another answer I seem to have stumbled upon with the Multiviews option disabled seems to be replacing all instances of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` so

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?(?!\.html/)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

becomes

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

No idea why this fixes it, but it definitely appears to behave more how you would expect, not sure if that's a bug or not. Still, huge help from the author of the other answer for getting me to this point.

Comment: Most likely there is some weirdness in your one Apache config that is making `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` NOT to expand to full path of `.php` or `.html` files. But good find ++

Comment: Maybe, I noticed that even if I replaced "privacy" with random letters that definitely did not exist as a file anywhere I still got the same problems, weird, but whatever lol